# Amortized time complexity of Union of disjoint sets

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, amortized-analysis

Suppose we represent each set using linked list representation where each node has 3 fields namely value, next pointer and pointer to the representative of the set. We maintain one index object(or representative) of each set with 3 fields head, tail and count(count of elements in set).

For Union of sets, we need to create a new set for each element and then take Union of them.

Each create operation of n elements takes O(1) time, so total = O(n).

Now during union we combine the elements in such a way that lower count set is appended to higher count one. So time complexity of Union of n sets will take O(n).

Total time complexity =O(n) + O(n) /2n = O(1).

So according to me time complexity for union operation should be O(1) but everywhere it's written O(n). Why is it so ?

Comment: Why do you divide by `2n`?

Comment: @Richard Total number of operations (n times union and n times create operation).

Comment: `O(n)` is the total time complexity. Dividing by `2n` would give you the cost per union (roughly - this isn't the best way to find it).

Comment: Can you provide an example source that says that the cost of the union is O(n)?

Comment: @templatetypedef http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-representation-disjoint-set-data-structures/

Comment: Can you elaborate about your specific algorithm? I want to make sure I understand what you're specifically proposing. Pseudocode would be appreciated.

Comment: @templatetypedef Suppose we have 3 elements 1,2,3. For each element we create a separate set with the attributes which I stated in the question. Now first we merge 1 and 2. Now 2nd set will be appended to set 1 in O(1) time(by just changing pointers) and then we update count variable of set 1 to 2 because it contains 2 elements now, 1 and 2. Now when we merge 3rd set with this newly combined set, we look at the count values of both these sets and choose the set with minimum count to be appended with the larger one. If we continue this way, every union operation will take O(1) time.

Comment: Gotcha. That isn't the approach that's described in the article you linked - that approach works by also iterating across the linked list during a merge and updating each item so that it points to the linked list head object, which is why they're getting a different time complexity.

Comment: @templatetypedef I want to know if my reasoning is correct or not. Because even in other articles union operation using linked list has time complexity of O(n). Maybe to find the set with minimum count takes O(n) , is it so ?

Comment: Linked-list-based approaches typically either have O(1) merges and O(n) finds or O(n) merges and O(1) finds. There are better approaches based on disjoint set forests.

Comment: @templatetypedef Yes I know there are better method like using path compression technique, but still I was having confusion with linked list representation. Also, what do you mean by O(n) find?Is it for finding representative for single element ? If that is the case then each element has a pointer to the representative node and we can find the representative set in O(1). If you meant finding the last node for merging then we have tail pointer from representative node to last element.